# Spring boot MissingServletRequestParameterException exception can't read Request parameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

From my Spring boot application, the url (http://localhost:8080/shop/passwordReset?token=390b28da-d84d-49c6-bc90-21a77dc0ce08) I have used to access below controller method

```
   @GetMapping("passwordReset")
    public ModelAndView getNewPassword(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        //verify token
        Password password = new Password();
        password.setToken(token);

        return new ModelAndView("resetPassword", "password", password);
    }
```

From this below Thymeleaf **'resetPassword'** page is shown without any problem.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>Reset Password</h1>
    </div>

    <form th:action="@{/passwordReset}" th:object="${password}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="matchingPassword">Confirm password</label>
            <input type="password"  name="matchingPassword" class="form-control" id="matchingPassword" placeholder="password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reset Password</button>
    </form>

    <div class="control-group">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

But from this **'resetPassword'** page when reset button is clicked I can’t reach to below controller method.

```
@PostMapping("passwordReset")
public String saveNewPassword(@RequestParam("token") String token,
                              @ModelAttribute("password") Password password, BindingResult result) {
...
}
```

Alwasy getting the error like:

> Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
> Required String parameter 'token' is not present]

Although I see the **token** is actually present using browser network tool, like this

[image]

**Remark**: the Password object looks like this :

```
@Entity
public class Password {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;
    private String matchingPassword;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String username;
    private String token;
}
```

Comment: The token isn't present it is only present in the refererrer header (which is the previous URL). Instead add it as a hidden form element to your form.

Comment: could you please tell me how to add the token field as hidden filed

Comment: Just add an input field with type hidden.

Comment: According to mentioned picture token is shown in url, but why it is not possible to fetch ?

Comment: It isn't in the URL. The previous URL (the referrer) is in the header.