# Spring Boot doesn't recognise Multipart parameter throwing MissingServletRequestParameterException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I'm using a custom `Multipart Resovler` for accepting a large file size for one end point and all others have default `max-file-size` set in `application.properties`.

```
public class CustomMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PortalMultipartResolver.class);

    @Autowired
    private MultipartProperties multipartProperties;

    @Override
    public MultipartHttpServletRequest resolveMultipart(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        log.info("Multipart resolver path : {}", httpServletRequest.getRequestURL());
        if (httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString().contains("bulkUpload")) {
            super.setMaxUploadSize(-1);
            super.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(-1);

            MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartHttpServletRequest = super.resolveMultipart(httpServletRequest);

            if(multipartProperties != null) {
                super.setMaxUploadSize(parseSize(this.multipartProperties.getMaxFileSize()));
                super.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(parseSize(this.multipartProperties.getMaxRequestSize()));
            } else {
                super.setMaxUploadSize(parseSize("10MB"));
                super.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(parseSize("10MB"));
            }

            return multipartHttpServletRequest;
        }
        return super.resolveMultipart(httpServletRequest);
    }
}
```

A exception is thrown:

```
Exception : Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present for URL

org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
```

I've checked other regarding this:

1. [Similar Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65394713/spring-boot-missingservletrequestparameterexception-exception-cant-read-request)

For this request I checked my request payload it contains all the information:
[Request Payload image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORjti.png)

Comment: Your resolver is flawed and will lead to issues in concurrent situations. You have 1 instance and are re-setting the values for each request, the last request wins. The issue with the parameters is generally because the requests has been processed or you should actually use `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestParam`.

Comment: I have used `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestParam` but I get this exception `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException`